# Creating a shortcut to execute a program with command-line parameters in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file

I have a problem and I am doing a custom installer for a program, the original installer program creates a shortcut on the desktop and the target of the shortcut is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Soft name\soft.exe" -soft run
```

In Inno Setup script I am using the following:

```
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe" -soft run; \
    IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico;
```

And this is the error that causes when I run the compiler to create the installer:

> Mismatched or misplaced quotes on parameter "Filename"

I have managed to correct the error but when the shortcut is created on the desktop, it appears without a target and does not find the exe of the program.

Important:

The direct access target should be the following because the program needs it like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Soft name\soft.exe" -soft run
```

How can I make the shortcut target created by Inno Setup be this way?

```
"C:\Program Files\Soft name\soft.exe" -soft run
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command-line parameters of the shortcut target program go to [`Parameters` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=Parameters):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-soft run"; IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico;
```