# Creating command-line parameters shortcut depending of language selected in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to use a conditional in command-line parameters - I have used this tutorial and it works great:
[Creating a shortcut to execute a program with command-line parameters in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907525/creating-a-shortcut-to-execute-a-program-with-command-line-parameters-in-inno-se)

I am creating an installer, I would like to know how to do if the user selects the Spanish language, the created shortcut has the parameter: `-spanish`

```
#define MyAppName "The software"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Inc."

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\English.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\The software\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-english"; IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the [`Languages` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams&anchor=Languages):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-english"; IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico; Languages: english
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-russian"; IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico; Languages: russian
...
```

---

Or use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) and the [`ActiveLanguage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_activelanguage). If your [language `Name`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=languagessection&anchor=Name) and the switch name always matches, it is very easy:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\Soft name"; Filename: "{app}\soft.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-{code:ActiveLanguage}"; IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico
```

If they do not match, you will have to implement a proxy function that translates the `ActiveLanguage` value to an equivalent switch name.