# Inno Setup : how to launch an executable with parameters

Tags: java, windows, installation, inno-setup

I have a custom Java runtime image for Windows called **java.exe** and I can simply execute `java -jar HelloWorld.jar` to run my HelloWorld application.
Using Inno Setup, I want to create an installer for my HelloWorld application. I can create an installer for **java.exe**, but obviously it would just run my custom Java image, whereas what I want is to run `java -jar HelloWorld.jar`.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Inno Setup does not seem to support application parameters.

I found a hack, which is to create a batch file that would execute my command. The problem is that it opens an extra CMD window. I was able to overcome this using a visual basic script that calls the batch file. It works, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: In your "hack" you can change `java` to `javaw` and you won't get a CMD window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for using javaw. However, as the title of the question suggests, it is about how to send parameters to a program, not about how to prevent a CMD window from opening.

Comment: I also found that the [icon] section in Inno supports parameters and a flag called “run minimized”. So in fact, I could just put the “-jar HelloWorlr.jar” as a parameter. I ended up doing something else however - I created a C based executable to run (via exec) the program with parameters. Feels cleaner and more robust to user changes

Comment: Is the installer supposed to run the java program during installation?  Or is it supposed to be setting up the java program for the user to run after installation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Inno Setup design, the way to pass parameters to the executable (Java in this case) is via the **parameters** configuration of the [icon] section. And using “minimized” in the **Flags** of the [icon] would cause the application to launch without opening any CMD windows.
The only downside of using [icon] parameters is that they are visible and modifiable by right clicking on the application icon. An alternative approach is to create a .bat file, or better yet: a .exe file that calls the application with the required parameters. If using .exe, then a simple call to execv would do. There’s no need to fork.

Comment: In your question you wrote about *running* your Java program in installer. I do not think your question even remotely suggests that you actually wanted your installer to create a (desktop) icon to run your program. + And using `javaw` is imo better solution than using "minimized" flag.

Comment: See [Creating a shortcut to execute a program with command-line parameters in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52907525/850848).